# Watir get INNER html of <span>

Tags: html, ruby, cucumber, watir

I'm trying to find a navigation link by iterating through a handful of spans with class 'menu-item-text'.  My goal is to compare what is inside the span tags to see if it is the right navigation control to click (there are no hard ids to go by.)  My code is like this:

```
navlinks = @browser.spans(:class, 'menu-item')
navlinks.each do |this|
    puts "'#{this.text}'"
    if this.text == link_name
        this.click
    break
end
```

I know for sure I'm getting the correct elements.  However, text is always an empty string. My second idea was to use .html instead of .text, but that returns something like this:

```
<span class="menu-item">Insights</span>
```

What I want is the "Insights" text inside the span, not the full html that includes the tag markup.  I have also tried using this.span.text, but that did not work either.

How can I target exclusively the inner html of an element through watir's content grabbing methods?

Thanks!

Comment: Are these navigation spans (links) a sort of dropdown menu where they are only visible in certain conditions (eg mouse hovers over a parent item)? The `.text` method only returns visible text. Given that it is returning an empty string suggests that the element is not actually visible.

Comment: Most of them are--they're part of a header navigation control.  There are about a dozen and three of them are not visible on the page I'm navigating away from, but iterating through any of them returns the empty string for .text .

Comment: That is rather unexpected. Any chance you can share the page or enough html to reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you are using Watir-Webdriver v0.6.9 or later, a `inner_html` method has been added for getting the inner HTML.

For the span:

```
<span class="menu-item">Insights</span>
```

You could do:

```
@browser.span(:class => 'menu-item').inner_html
#=> "Insights"
```

Similarly, you could try using this method in your loop instead of `.text`.

Note that depending on the uniqueness of your text, you might be able to simply check if the text appears in element's (outer) html:

```
@browser.spans(:class => 'menu-item', :html => /#{link_name}/).click
```

Comment: Thanks, that did what I was looking for.  I thought I had tried that before, but maybe I was calling .innerHtml instead of .inner_html .  I should have remembered that Ruby uses a different naming system from what I'm used to.